# Rails & strong_parameters 'required parameter missing'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, strong-parameters

I'm working on creating 'retweet'(restream) functionality for one of my projects, but I keep running into this error:

```
Required parameter missing: restream
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Here's my setup. Any ideas?

**Models**

```
#app/models/member.rb
Class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :statuses
end

#app/models/status.rb
Class Status< ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :member
    has_many :restreams, class_name: "Status", foreign_key: "restream_id"
end
```

**Restream**

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :statuses do
    member do
        post :retweet
    end
end

#app/controllers/statuses_controller.rb
def restream
    @restream = Status.new(restream_params)
    @restream.save
end

private

def restream_params
    params.require(:restream).permit(:restream_id, :content).merge(member_id: current_user.id)
end

#app/views/statuses/show.html.erb
<%= link_to image_tag("Re-Stream 3.png", class: "act_actions", title: "Restream", alt: "Restream"), restream_status_path(status.id), method: :post, :class => "btn restream" %>
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear here. You don't pass required `restream` param into `restream` action.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `restream param`. You also need to send it in get, and to specify the value of your `restream_param` because it is a `link_to.`

```
#app/views/statuses/show.html.erb
<%= link_to image_tag("Re-Stream 3.png", class: "act_actions", title: "Restream", alt: "Restream"), restream_status_path(status.id), params.merge({:restream => "the value you want to pass"})  method: :get, :class => "btn restream" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is best explained by looking at the [`params hash` in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#hash-and-array-parameters):

---

**Example**

> { "company": { "name": "acme", "address": "123 Carrot Street" } }
>
> You'll get params[:company] as { "name" => "acme", "address" => "123
>   Carrot Street" }

---

**Strong Params**

For your `strong_params` to work, your params hash needs to look like this:

```
{ "restream": {"your":"params", "go":"here"} }
```

The problem is your params hash will look like this:

```
{"your":"param", "goes":"here"}
```

---

**Fix**

There are two ways to fix this:

```
def restream_params
    params.permit(:restream_id, :content).merge(member_id: current_user.id)
end
```

This will allow the `:restream_id` and `:content params` without the need for them to be embedded in the `:restream` option of the params hash

The other option is to pass the `:restream` param through your link. Sidney's answer was great for this, but I would use [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html), as I know this sets the params hash as required:

```
<%= form_for @restream %>
    <%= text_field :restream_id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: ok I see what I was missing so I changed my code to: `<%= link_to image_tag("Re-Stream 3.png", class: "act_actions", title: "Restream", alt: "Restream"), restream_status_path(status.id, restream: "my_restream_object"), method: :post, :class => "btn restream" %>` I guess I'm just not sure what object I should be passing to make things work